# In Google Analytics, what is the Medium and Source for a page view that was originated from an internal link?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

In Google Analytics, whenever we log a `page_view` event it will also log the **"Medium"** and the **"Source"** for that page view.

For example, if a user came through **Organic search from Google**, you would see a page view with the following Medium and Source:

[image]

**QUESTION**

But what if after the first page viewed, the **user clicks on an internal link from your website to see another page.**

What would it consider as Medium and Source for this next `page_view` event that was generated by clicking on a link of your own website?

Does it also count as a page view "Organic from Google" since you've landed on the site from Google at first? Or does Analytics logs as something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GA uses last *non-direct* click attribution method.
By default your own domain should be on the GA Property's Referral Exclusion List, so as to not overwrite the originating source/medium.

So, taking that into account, all pageviews etc for the current session *should* be attributed to Organic/google, unless something like custom utm campaign tagging is being used on internal links (which they should not be).

Comment: I was expecting that, but wasn't sure. I was thinking that with this behavior I would lose the information of which page (i.e: which pageview hit) the user **first** landed when coming from Google, since all pageviews on that session would have Google as source. But I guess that that information (for the first page of the session) is kept as "Entrance", right? Thanks you!

Comment: Landing pages, however yes also Entrances. Only real difference is that Landing Page is a dimension and session based, Entrances is a metric and hit based, which will show differences if trying to combine the two different scopes.